# Produce a list of y-values (function-values) at specific x-values taken from a list

Tags: python

I would like to produce a list of y-vales (i.e. function-values) based on x-values taken from a list.

I have programed a function `eval_poly(p,x)` which produces the y-value for a function p at a certain point x:

```
def eval_poly(p,x): 
ans = 0
for degree,coeff in enumerate(p):
    ans += coeff*x**degree # ekvationen som ska räknas
return ans
```

And I also have created a list with the x-values I want to use (the idea is to later plot a graph with these):

```
def plot_poly(p,x_start=-10,x_end=10,color='b'):

    lst = list(range(x_start, x_end + 1))
    print(lst)
```

And now I want to calculate all y-values using `eval_poly(p, x)` for all x-values. How can I do that? This is what I have tried:

```
 for x in lst:
    lst_y = list(eval_poly(p,x))
    print(lst_y)
```

But I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for a list comprehension:

```
ys = [eval_poly(p,x) for x in lst]
```

This iterates over `lst`, and applies your function to each `x` value, then saves the result in a list.

This is equivalent to:

```
ys = []
for x in lst:
    ys.append(eval_poly(p,x))
```

Which I suspect is what you were originally trying to do.

Your original error was because your function returns a number, but `list` is expecting an iterable to turn into a `list`.